# Android TextView: Phantom Padding When Padding Set To 0

Tags: android, textview

I have `TextView`:

```
    text.setTypeface(font);
    text.setWidth((int)width);
    text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    text.setHeight((int)height);
    text.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
    text.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

However even with the padding set to `0`, and `setIncludeFontPadding` to `false` and I set the font size to the height of the `TextView` I still get this:

[image]

If I set the padding to have negative values like -30, It fixes it:

`text.setPadding(0,-30,0,-30);`

[image]

My question is why do I have to do this? Where is this phantom padding coming from? And where am I finding this arbitrary (-30 in this specific case) value I need to set it to, so that the text fills the height?

**Update**

Trying @Mike M. 's solution I got these results. When it was a positive number, it was a smaller size than when it was a negative one. Both of them still had padding:
[image]
[image]

**Update 2** Here the custom class in full:

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.SparseIntArray;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Special textview which gracefully handles resizing.
 */
public class iTextView extends TextView
{
    // Set true to remove phantom padding
    public boolean trimPadding = false;

    //region Interfaces

    private interface SizeTester
    {
        /**
         * Interface for scaling text to fit.
         * @param suggestedSize Size of text to be tested.
         * @param availableSpace Available space in which text must fit.
         * @return An integer < 0 if after applying {@code suggestedSize} to
         *         text, it takes less space than {@code availableSpace}, > 0
         *         otherwise.
         */
         int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSpace);
    }
    //endregion

    //region Variables

    private static final int NO_LINE_LIMIT = -1;

    private RectF _textRect = new RectF();
    private RectF _availableSpaceRect;

    private SparseIntArray _textCachedSizes;

    private TextPaint _paint;

    private float _maxTextSize;
    private float _spacingMult;
    private float _spacingAdd;
    private float _minTextSize;

    private int _widthLimit;
    private int _maxLines;

    private boolean _enableSizeCache;
    private boolean _initialized;
    //endregion

    //region Constructors

    public iTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);

        initialize();
    }

    public iTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);

        initialize();
    }

    public iTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        initialize();
    }
    //endregion

    //region Initialization

    private void initialize()
    {
        _spacingMult = 1.0f;
        _spacingAdd = 0.0f;
        _minTextSize = 20;

        _enableSizeCache = true;

        _paint = new TextPaint(getPaint());

        _maxTextSize = getTextSize();

        _availableSpaceRect = new RectF();

        _textCachedSizes = new SparseIntArray();

        if (_maxLines == 0)
        {
            // No value was assigned during construction
            _maxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        }

        _initialized = true;
    }
    //endregion

    //region Text Value

    @Override
    public void setText(final CharSequence text, BufferType type)
    {
        super.setText(text, type);

        adjustTextSize(text.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start, final int before,
                                 final int after)
    {
        super.onTextChanged(text, start, before, after);

        reAdjust();
    }
    //endregion

    //region Text Sizing

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(float size)
    {
        _maxTextSize = size;

        _textCachedSizes.clear();

        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    /**
     * Ensures the text is as big as possible for the text area.
     */
    public void setTextSizeToMaxFit()
    {
        _maxTextSize = 999;

        _textCachedSizes.clear();

        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void setTextSize(int unit, float size)
    {
        Context context = getContext();
        Resources resources;

        if (context == null)
        {
            resources = Resources.getSystem();
        } else
        {
            resources = context.getResources();
        }

        _maxTextSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(unit, size, resources.getDisplayMetrics());

        _textCachedSizes.clear();

        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    /**
     * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
     *
     * @param minTextSize
     */
    public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize)
    {
        _minTextSize = minTextSize;
        reAdjust();
    }

    private void reAdjust() {
        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    private void adjustTextSize(String string)
    {
        if (!_initialized)
        {
            return;
        }
        int startSize = (int) _minTextSize;
        int heightLimit = getMeasuredHeight() - getCompoundPaddingBottom() - getCompoundPaddingTop();

        _widthLimit = getMeasuredWidth() - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();

        _availableSpaceRect.right = _widthLimit;
        _availableSpaceRect.bottom = heightLimit;

        super.setTextSize
        (
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,
            efficientTextSizeSearch(startSize, (int)_maxTextSize, mSizeTester, _availableSpaceRect)
        );
    }

    private final SizeTester mSizeTester = new SizeTester()
    {
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public int onTestSize(int suggestedSize, RectF availableSPace)
        {
            _paint.setTextSize(suggestedSize);

            String text = getText().toString();

            boolean singleLine = getMaxLines() == 1;

            if (singleLine)
            {
                _textRect.bottom = _paint.getFontSpacing();
                _textRect.right = _paint.measureText(text);
            } else
            {
                StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout
                                      (
                                          text,
                                          _paint,
                                          _widthLimit,
                                          Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                                          _spacingMult,
                                          _spacingAdd,
                                          true
                                      );
                // Return early if no more lines
                if (getMaxLines() != NO_LINE_LIMIT && layout.getLineCount() > getMaxLines())
                {
                    return 1;
                }
                _textRect.bottom = layout.getHeight();

                int maxWidth = -1;

                for (int i = 0; i < layout.getLineCount(); i++)
                {
                    if (maxWidth < layout.getLineWidth(i))
                    {
                        maxWidth = (int)layout.getLineWidth(i);
                    }
                }

                _textRect.right = maxWidth;
            }

            _textRect.offsetTo(0, 0);

            if (availableSPace.contains(_textRect))
            {
                // May be too small, Will find the best match later
                return -1;
            } else
            {
                // Too big
                return 1;
            }
        }
    };

    /**
     * Enables or disables size caching, enabling it will improve performance
     * where its animating a value inside TextView. This stores the font
     * size against getText().length() Enabling it as 0
     * takes more space than 1 on some fonts and so on.
     * @param enable Enable font size caching
     */
    public void enableSizeCache(boolean enable)
    {
        _enableSizeCache = enable;

        _textCachedSizes.clear();

        adjustTextSize(getText().toString());
    }

    private int efficientTextSizeSearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester, RectF availableSpace)
    {
        if (!_enableSizeCache)
        {
            return binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);
        }
        String text = getText().toString();

        int key = text == null ? 0 : text.length();

        int size = _textCachedSizes.get(key);
        if (size != 0)
        {
            return size;
        }
        size = binarySearch(start, end, sizeTester, availableSpace);

        _textCachedSizes.put(key, size);

        return size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int width, int height, int oldwidth,int oldheight)
    {
        _textCachedSizes.clear();

        super.onSizeChanged(width, height, oldwidth, oldheight);

        if (width != oldwidth || height != oldheight)
        {
            reAdjust();
        }
    }

    private static int binarySearch(int start, int end, SizeTester sizeTester,RectF availableSpace)
    {
        int lastBest = start;
        int low = start;
        int high = end - 1;
        int mid = 0;
        while (low <= high)
        {
            mid = (low + high) >>> 1;

            int midValCmp = sizeTester.onTestSize(mid, availableSpace);

            if (midValCmp < 0)
            {
                lastBest = low;
                low = mid + 1;
            } else if (midValCmp > 0)
            {
                high = mid - 1;
                lastBest = high;
            } else
            {
                return mid;
            }
        }

        // Make sure to return last best
        // This is what should always be returned
        return lastBest;
    }
    //endregion

    //region Text Lines

    @Override
    public void setMaxLines(int maxlines)
    {
        super.setMaxLines(maxlines);

        _maxLines = maxlines;

        reAdjust();
    }

    public int getMaxLines()
    {
        return _maxLines;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine()
    {
        super.setSingleLine();

        _maxLines = 1;

        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setSingleLine(boolean singleLine)
    {
        super.setSingleLine(singleLine);
        if (singleLine)
        {
            _maxLines = 1;
        } else
        {
            _maxLines = NO_LINE_LIMIT;
        }
        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLines(int lines)
    {
        super.setLines(lines);

        _maxLines = lines;

        reAdjust();
    }

    @Override
    public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult)
    {
        super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);

        _spacingMult = mult;

        _spacingAdd = add;
    }
    //endregion

    //region Padding Fix

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if (trimPadding)
        {
            trimVertical();
        }

        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void trimVertical()
    {
        final Layout layout   = getLayout();
        final Rect textBounds = new Rect();

        if (layout == null)
        {
            Log.d("Layout is null","" + layout);
            return;
        }

        int baseline = layout.getLineBaseline(0);

        getTextBounds(0, textBounds);

        final int pTop     = baseline + textBounds.top;
        final int lastLine = getLineCount() - 1;

        baseline           = layout.getLineBaseline(lastLine);

        getTextBounds(lastLine, textBounds);

        final int pBottom  = layout.getHeight() - baseline - textBounds.bottom + 1;

        setPadding(getPaddingLeft(), -pTop, getPaddingRight(), -pBottom);
    }

    private void getTextBounds(int line, Rect bounds)
    {
        final String s  = getText().toString();
        final int start = getLayout().getLineStart(line);
        final int end   = getLayout().getLineEnd(line);
        getPaint().getTextBounds(s, start, end, bounds);
    }
    //endregion
}
```

Comment: It could be due to the paddin added in its parent Layout

Comment: OK, I had a look at your custom `TextView`. My solution is not compatible with what that class is doing to resize its contents. If I get time later, I might see what I can come up with for that. Also, you definitely need to clearly point out in your question that you're using a custom `View` class. There is no simple setting on `TextView` to remove that extra padding, so anyone who might answer your question needs to know what that class is doing. You might also want to include some of the relevant parts of that class in your question, since links to off-site code are rather frowned upon here.

Comment: Good points Ill take some time to update this when I get back to the office on Tuesday! Thanks for the help so far, you've invested significant time!